# Checking for existence of item in array

Tags: c++

Is there a code that will check if a certain string is inside an array?
For example I have a string "John" then I need to check if "John" is already in the array names[10].

Comment: It seems that you are just asking "how do I do this?" That is not a very good way to ask a question, because it means that you have not at least checked documentation before asking people.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) does exactly that:

```
auto i = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), "John");

if (i != std::end(a)) … // item found!
```

However, beware that this does a linear pass over the elements. That’s not a problem for 10 items but it becomes inefficient quickly with larger number. For very large sets, use [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead of an array, to attain (theoretically) constant runtime. Alternatively, if you know that the array is sorted you may employ [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) to attain logarithmic runtime.

Here’s the same code, wrapped inside a convenience function:

```
template <typename It, typename T>
bool contains(It begin, It end, T const& value) {
    return std::find(begin, end, value) != end;
}
```

And here’s a convenience overload for C arrays:

```
template <typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
bool contains(T (&arr)[N], U const& value) {
    return std::find(arr, arr + N, value) != arr + N;
}
```

(The syntax for passing arrays to functions is a bit weird.)

Comment: does std::find need any header?
#..?

Comment: never mind I found it though thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, I will be using it as an expression for It would be like:

if (The word "John" is in array name[]) Something like this?

Comment: If you want it shorter, wrap it in a function (the `find` + check against `end`), but that function should be a template to be reusable among different containers.

Comment: "The syntax for passing arrays to functions is a bit weird." AFAIK it's not possible to pass arrays *by value*, only by reference or as a pointer. But good to know how to pass it by reference with length information, I always wanted to know this!

Comment: That aside, why not writing an overload for all containers? http://ideone.com/M13C27

Comment: @leemes Feasible, but the idiomatic interface for container algorithms is (still – this might change in the future) a pair of iterators. My code is currently easier to generalise (pass parts of a range), although the same is possible with yours, but requires you to manually wrap the iterators into a container wrapper.

Comment: That's an *overload* we're talking about. But that aside, since in 99% of the cases we want the whole sequence, I prefer wrapping two iterators into a single range wrapper in 1% of the cases over "unwrapping" begin and end iterators in 99% of the cases. The most annoying thing about std algorithms imho. But that discussion is clearly off-topic ;)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to go archaic:

```
function in_array(String my_array[], String findthis){
   len=sizeof my_array;
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(my_array[i]==findthis){
           return true;
      }
   }
     return false;
}
```

then

```
in_array(array_of_strings, "john");
```

I wrote this hastily and I'm very tired, but hopefully it can be of some use.

Comment: You cannot pass arrays by value in C++. Your code passes a pointer. `sizeof my_array` consequently does the wrong thing.

Comment: this comment help me though.. xD it gives me the idea to what I need, thanks :D

Comment: That's a strange dialect of C++ you're writing in...

Comment: dThanks? I'm more of a python kind of guy O.o . . . I'm in network security, not programming. From what I remember when I learned rudimentary C++ years ago in the tenth grade is pretty.. well... rudimentary. I know it's wrong. Again, I'm very tired.

Comment: It's ok to not know everything. But then you should also accept negative feedback if you post wrong solutions.